# Why Googlebot is crawling only one page?

Tags: seo, googlebot, web-crawlers, anchor

I am trying to understand why Google bot is crawling only one page only on my website.

At the Google console I registered a small XML sitemap with 9 URLs. Only one URL I marked as a high priority (0.8) and that changes on daily basis. This URL is `/Home/Index`

Based on [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/134144/117873) I removed all other sitemaps, and on `Home/Index` I placed several anchors to the pages that I wanted to be crawled too, and these anchors are changing each visit to the new anchors. And pages behind these anchors are having other several anchors, and so on.

What I am seeing, Google bot is crawling only `/Home/Index` multiple times per day and seems to be ignoring all pages behind the anchors. What might be the reason and how to change this?

I can also see that other bots are crawling those anchors.

Comment: How do you know what Googlebot is crawling?  Are you watching your access logs, or are you basing it based on what Google is indexing?

Comment: How old is your website?  Did you just launch it in the last couple weeks?  How long has it been since you created the links?

Comment: Are you using any "single page" technology on your site that renders your site with JavaScript?   Are you using Angular or React?

Comment: Google ignores the `priority` field in XML sitemaps.  I usually recommend omitting that field along with the `last modified` field which is also ignored.  Most sites just need the a list of `loc` in their XML sitemap and nothing else.    It shouldn't hurt to have an XML sitemap even if it doesn't help Google index and rank your content.  Having a sitemap just isn't sufficient for SEO.   It is safe (and probably better) to have your sitemap AND links to your pages.

Comment: Website has one year already. I know that bot is crawling, because I see in my logs the `user-agent` name and area visited. Other bots are crawling subpages with no problem. I juse pure JS on my pages, but the anchors are loading with HTML only, so bot does not need to wait for it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller And btw, are XML sitemaps better or TXT with pure URLs?

Comment: XML allow for images, videos, and hreflang to be included while txt sitemaps do not.  XML sitemaps also support sitemap index files for sites with more than 50,000 pages.   You probably don't need any of those features, so TXT would be fine, but XML is also fine.

Comment: So you see Googlebot in your access log and it only ever fetches the one page?

Comment: Actually yes, it is crawling my Home/Index several times per day. But please note, that I removed sitemap indexes and left only sitemap with a few URLs

Comment: Anyway, I think to add TXT sitemaps (easier to generate them), and XML sitemap indexes, if it does not hurt my SEO and indexing, as you mentioned before.

Comment: Can you inspect the URLs in Google Search Console?   Google should be able to tell if it ever crawled the URLs there.  Could you share your site with us so we can check it?

Comment: Actually I have changed routing recently and I am permanently redirecting to the new URLs and yes, many of the old URLs were crawled in the past, but not recently, because of some reason.

Comment: Google almost completely ignores most pages of small not-so-popular websites. For my own site of 150 pages, most of which have been around for years, using `site:` only lists 5 pages. Even when I used Webmaster, nowhere near all pages were listed with no reasons as to why so many were ignored. This means that if a person read one of my pages, they most likely will never be able to find it by searching with Google, even if they use `site:`. Google is not operating in good faith in providing their services if they deliberately ignore most pages of a site.

Comment: I am finding it hard to believe that Google crawls the same site multiple times a day.  Is the OP getting confused with Analytics ?

Comment: Please check that you have added the sitemap correctly into the google search console or you have implemented the google search console tag correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The priority setting has no influence on what the Google Crawler will crawl at the end. If one  webpage has a low number of pages Google will crawl them all. Or do you have any specific settings in the robots.txt? If you upload a Sitemap in the robots which consists of one page other pages will not be regarded.

Comment: Google may crawl them, but deliberately ignores many, or even most, while providing no reason why.